# Express.js not finding stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

I'm working on an app using the MEAN stack, and I'm having trouble getting my main index page to pick up my stylesheet. Running **node server** works fine, the index.html page is rendering, and there are no console errors. Hitting http://localhost:3000/public/css/app.css returns the CSS as expected. So the file is there and accessible, but the styles aren't being applied to the index page.

Any idea what's going on?

**./server.js**

```
var config = require('./server/config/environment');
var express = require('./server/config/express');

var app = express();

app.listen(config.port, function() {
    console.log('Server is listening on port %d', config.port);
});

exports = module.exports = app;
```

**./server/config/express.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    require('../server.routes.js')(app);
    app.use("/public/css", express.static(path.resolve('public/css')));
    app.get('/public/css/app.css', function(request, response) {
        response.sendFile(path.resolve('public/css/app.css'));
    });

    return app;
};
```

**./server/server.routes.js**

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    app.get('/', require('./server.controller').render);
};
```

**./server/server.controller.js**

```
module.exports.render = function(request, response) {
    response.render('index');
};
```

**./views/index.ejs**

```
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" src="/public/css/app.css">
</head>
```

**./public/css/app.css**

```
body {
    margin: 70px 20px 20px 20px;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the css file is not served by your backend?
Try `background-color:red;`..
Do you see an Error in your JS Console in the Browser?

Comment: move your `require('../server.routes.js')(app);` below static files handlers.

Comment: Tried setting the background color to red--no change. I also tried moving the require('../server.routes.js')(app); below the static file handlers, and no luck there either (after restarting the node server).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

./views/index.ejs

```html
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
</head>
```

./server/config/express.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');

module.exports = function() {
    var app = express();

    app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
    require('../server.routes.js')(app);
    app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')));

    return app;
};
```

When you use `express.static()` you are registering that as a public folder, meaning the client doesn't need to actually know what the name of the folder is. Essentially what you were doing was calling

```html
<head>
    <base href="/">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/public/css/app.css">
</head>
```

Usually people register a base folder and then put the css in the css/ subfolder and the js in the js/ subfolder

EDIT: @HydraHorn realized on his own that he was using `<link src="...">` instead of `<link href="...">`. That said it still would not have worked without the changes to `express.static()`. I have made the changes above to not confuse future visitors

Comment: `express.static` middleware **must** be defined earlier than application routes.

Comment: After making this change, I'm still having the same issue, sadly.

Comment: When you load the index page are look at network in the dev-tools are you getting a 404 error?

Comment: *facepalm* - I needed to change <link src=""> to <link href="">.

I'm going to accept this answer, though, because without changing the express.static call, this would still be broken.

Comment: Ya sorry I should have noticed that. Everyone makes those kind of mistakes from time to time. Thanks for accepting my answer. I made some small edits for future visitors